# knockout js external template engine - templates not being loaded

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the knockout js external template engine. It seems to be pretty straightforward. But only a few of my templates are getting loaded, others are not getting included and there are no errors in my firebug console. 
If i include the HTML inline then it works. After i move them into the template it does not get loaded.

The other templates that are getting loaded do not have the "data-bind="with:..." option. They are plain html.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance for your help

**Main HTML**

```
<body>
  <div 
   class="tab-pane fade" 
   id="personal" 
   data-bind="template: { name: 'personal'}"
  ></div>
</body>
```

**My Template HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-bind= "with : dashboard.user">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.

My main html div which has the template has the same id as the template name, so it was failing silently. I just found out the hard way. I renamed my template files to have the Tmpl suffix and it started to work.

```
<body>
  <div 
    class="tab-pane fade" 
    id="personal" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'personalTmpl'}"
  ></div>
</body>
```